# Swift UI : Create different links in a list

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm a beginner developper, I created a list and I'm looking for to create different links according to items on my list.

Here is an example of my list :

```
import SwiftUI

struct Categorykata: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{ //Permet de scroller//
            List(Category.list,
                 id:\.id){
                Category in CatKataView (category: Category)
                    .overlay(
                        NavigationLink( //pour que cela soit cliquable).
                            destination:KarateShotokanView (), //Fait référence à notre page de départ.//
                            label: {
                                EmptyView()
                            }
                                      ).opacity(0)
                        )
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                .navigationTitle("Select your Category")
        }
    }
}

struct CatKataView: View {
    let category : Category
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.white
                .cornerRadius(8)
            HStack{
                image
                info
                Spacer()
            }.padding()
        }.shadow(color:Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 8, x:0, y:2)
    }
}

private extension CatKataView {
    var image : some View {
        Image(category.image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    }
    var info : some View{
        VStack(alignment:.leading, spacing:5) {
            Text(category.name)
                .font(.headline)
                .lineLimit(2)
            Text(category.description)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .lineLimit(2)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    Categorykata()
}
```

For my list I use a swift file called "Category"
Here is the code :

```
import Foundation

struct Category: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let image: String
}

extension Category{
    static let list: [Category] = [
        Category(name: "Kata", description: "Category de Kata basique", image: "colorbelt"),
        Category(name: "Kata Superieur", description: "Category de Kata superieur", image: "blackbelt"),
    ]
}
```

When I do click on my View, the link is directed me to the same page or I would like to get a link for each items I have on my view, how to do that ?

Thank you for your futur answer.
Vintsent

Explaining me the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```swift
struct Categorykata: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView { //Permet de scroller.
            List(Category.list) { cat in
                NavigationLink( //pour que cela soit cliquable).
                    destination: DetailKataView(category: cat), //Fait référence à notre page de départ.
                    label: {
                        CatKataView(category: cat)
                    })
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationTitle("Select your Category")
        }
    }
}
```

`label` is what appears in the list on the left, destination is the detail view, so inject the selected Category there.

---

I changed a few other things:

- Always use lower case for variables in Swift (like `cat` not `Category`).
- No need for the List `id:` initalizer if the model you supply is already conforming to `Identifiable`.
- Use `.listStyle(.plain)` instead of `.listStyle(PlainListStyle())`